# Rails 3 + JQuery-File-Upload + Multiple Files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, image, carrierwave, jquery-file-upload

I am currently using Carrierwave to allow my users to upload (1) file per event created. I would like to expand the options and offer my customers to availability to add multiple images per event.

I am stuck on how to complete this task.

I know I want to use the jquery-file upload project: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html  but stuck on if I need to create a new model called "galleries" for this and assign each event a gallery or if I can simply using the setup I have now and allow the user to upload, lets say, 5 files per event without having to fill out five individual file fields and have javascript work on that end.

Any suggestions? Do I need to use nested models as per: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

TIA